# nginx - selective rewrite within a location block

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Assuming a location block needs to handle URLs like

- /test_api/group_1/version   (several URLs fall in this group.  For example, /test_api/aaa/version, /test_api/bbb/version)
- /test_api/group_2/revision  (several other URLs fall in this group.  For example, /test_api/yyy/revision, /test_api/zzz/revision)

How can I selectively rewrite "/test_api/group_1/version" while passing "/test_api/group_2/revision" to a default server within a location block?  If that's not possible, are there other ways to achieve the same goal.
Below is my current non-discriminating location block.

```
location /test_api {
    types    { application/json json; }
    root     /usr/local/www/data;
    rewrite  "/test_api/([^/]+)/version(.*)/?$"   /api_response/test_api_$1.json   break;
}
```

Comment: Might be better addressed in SuperUser SE

Answer (score 1):

when you make two locations like

```
location /test_api/group_1/version {
  ...
}

location /test_api {
  ...
}
```

the LONGEST one will always match, so yours group_2 will not match 1st rule

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have many URLs that fall in each group so I can't code it like that.  I've updated the question to make it more clear.